# Norm of Operator Proof

Tags: inequality, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I'm stuck on this problem that I can't seem to figure out. Here's the problem.[image: the problem]

To note, equation 2.42 says that

$$||T|| = \sup \{ ||Tu||: u \in C([a,b]), ||u|| = 1 \}$$

where $T$ is defined,

$$(Tf)(x) = \int_a^b G(x,\xi) f(\xi)\, d \xi$$

and $G$ is the Green's function for the Sturm-Liouville system,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(p \frac{du}{dx}  \right) + ru + \lambda w u = 0$$

---

The first part is very simple.

$$|\langle Tu, u \rangle| \leq ||Tu|| \cdot ||u|| \leq ||T|| \cdot ||u||^2$$

and then we're only dealing with $||u|| = 1$ so this is equivalent to $||T||$. However, the second part of this proof I can't figure out. I don't know how to obtain the equation they have in the hint. If I can obtain that it seems fairly straightforward that when $v = \frac{Tu}{||Tu||}$ we have,

$$\frac{1}{||Tu||}\langle Tu, Tu\rangle \leq \sup |\langle Tu, u\rangle| \Longrightarrow ||Tu|| \leq \sup |\langle Tu, u\rangle|$$

This holds for all $||u|| = 1$ and so we must have $\sup |\langle Tu, u\rangle| = ||T||$.

However, I don't see how they get that equation in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Is $T$ self-adjoint? Otherwise this formula might be false - consider antisymmetric operators.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy sorry, I forgot to add the definition of $T$. It's edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an implicit hypothesis that $T$ is self-adjoint (otherwise the desired formula might be false - take antysymetric $T$).

Let $$a=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(Tx,x)|.$$

You can write that $$(Tx,y) = \frac14(T(x+y),(x+y))-\frac14(T(x-y),(x-y)),$$
hence
$$|(Tx,y)|\le \frac a4 (\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2) =\frac a2 (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)  $$

We also know that $\sup_{\|x\|=1,\,\|y\|=1}|(Tx,y)|=\|T\|$, hence we get that $\|T\|\le a$, which finilises the proof.